# class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.Parameterized

Tags: java, generics

Java 11

I need to get generic type on runtime.

Here client code:

```
     var dataTemplateClient = new DataTemplateJdbc<Client>(dbExecutor, entitySQLMetaDataClient); 

    public class Client {
        @Id
        private Long id;
        private String name;
    }
```

Here code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

    public class DataTemplateJdbc<T> implements DataTemplate<T> {
        private final DbExecutor dbExecutor;
        private final EntitySQLMetaData entitySQLMetaData;
    
        public DataTemplateJdbc(DbExecutor dbExecutor, EntitySQLMetaData entitySQLMetaData) {
            this.dbExecutor = dbExecutor;
            this.entitySQLMetaData = entitySQLMetaData;
            ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            Type type = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
```

But I get error in this line:

```
ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at mypackage.DataTemplateJdbc.<init>(DataTemplateJdbc.java:26)
```

Comment: Well that won't work. `DataTemplateJdbc<T>` doesn't have a generic superclass, it extends `Object`. You'd need `FooClass extends DataTemplateJdbc<Something>` to get the generic type out of it (from `FooClass`).

Comment: What you want is impossible. All that `getGenericX` stuff will, at best, get you `T`. Just literally: "A type variable with no bounds whose name is T". If this was possible, don't you think java would have made it a little easier to get at?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you are trying to do won't work.  You cannot get the actual type associated with `T` at runtime.

When you call `getClass()` on a `DataTemplateJdbc`, it will give you the `Class` object that represents the erased type.  That is all that is available.

The typecast is bound to fail.  That `Class` can never represent a parameterized type<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1- The Java compiler has no way of knowing that.  As far as the compiler is concerned, `Class` implements `Type` which is a supertype of `ParameterizedType.  It "thinks" that the type cast *could* succeed ... so it doesn't flag this as a compilation error.</sup>